# decompress name

Tags: python, perl, awk

what is the easiest way to decompress a data name?

For example, change compressed form:

```
abc[3:0]
```

into decompressed form:

```
abc[3]
abc[2]
abc[1]
abc[0]
```

preferable 1 liner :)

Comment: By "data name" do you mean "variable" or is "abc[3:0]" a string that you want broken up into four separate strings?

Comment: Unless you're trying to do a language-comparison question, python, perk and awk tags are almost certainly not appropriate. Given the syntax you're using, 'python' seems somewhat appropriate.

Comment: @jkerian: except of course that in Python abc[3:0] would get you, err, 0 items starting at the third, not items 3,2,1,0.

Comment: i think there is misinterpretation on my quetion,

Comment: what i want is break a text "abc[3:0]" to "abc[3]" "abc[2]"....all these are not a variable but a literal text

Comment: @user can you edit your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little pyparsing exercise that I've done in the past, adapted to your example (also supports multiple ranges and unpaired indexes, all separated by commas - see the last test case):

```
from pyparsing import (Suppress, Word, alphas, alphanums, nums, delimitedList, 
    Combine, Optional, Group)

LBRACK,RBRACK,COLON = map(Suppress,"[]:")

ident = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_")
integer = Combine(Optional('-') + Word(nums))
integer.setParseAction(lambda t : int(t[0]))
intrange = Group(integer + COLON + integer)

rangedIdent = ident("name") + LBRACK + delimitedList(intrange|integer)("indexes") + RBRACK

def expandIndexes(t):
    ret = []
    for ind in t.indexes:
        if isinstance(ind,int):
            ret.append("%s[%d]" % (t.name, ind))
        else:
            offset = (-1,1)[ind[0] < ind[1]]
            ret.extend(
                "%s[%d]" % (t.name, i) for i in range(ind[0],ind[1]+offset,offset)
                )
    return ret
rangedIdent.setParseAction(expandIndexes)

print rangedIdent.parseString("abc[0:3]")
print rangedIdent.parseString("abc[3:0]")
print rangedIdent.parseString("abc[0:3,7,14:16,24:20]")
```

Prints:

```
['abc[0]', 'abc[1]', 'abc[2]', 'abc[3]']
['abc[3]', 'abc[2]', 'abc[1]', 'abc[0]']
['abc[0]', 'abc[1]', 'abc[2]', 'abc[3]', 'abc[7]', 'abc[14]', 'abc[15]', 'abc[16]', 'abc[24]', 'abc[23]', 'abc[22]', 'abc[21]', 'abc[20]']
```

Comment: cool!, are you able to revert back from decompress to compress?

Comment: I think that can be left as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
#!perl -w

use strict;
use 5.010;

my @abc = qw/ a b c d /;
say join( " ", reverse @abc[0..3] );
```

Or if you wanted them into separate variables:

```
my( $abc3, $abc2, $abc1, $abc0 ) = reverse @abc[0..3];
```

**Edit:** Per your clarification:

```
my $str = "abc[3:0]";
$str =~ /(abc)\[(\d+):(\d+)\]/;
my $base = $1;
my $from = ( $2 < $3 ? $2 : $3 );
my $to = ( $2 > $3 ? $2 : $3 );
my @strs;
foreach my $num ( $from .. $to ) {
  push @strs, $base . '[' . $num . ']';
}
```

Comment: So does foreach do all values from $from to $to inclusive, or only up to $to-1.  How does this work with negative indexes?

Comment: Save three lines of code and use of three nugatory match variables by assigning the results of the match expression to the three named scalar vars directly, and doing only one comparison in the foreach expression: `$from<$to : $from..$to : reverse $from..$to` (untested)